# Default choice of SVM position on ROC curve

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, libsvm

I've got a question about where the sklearn SVM classifier, on default settings, will be on a ROC curve or, failing that, how to find out. I've been of the assumption that the ROC curve was a description of general performance, so trying to find the exact position of the classifier was new to me.

Assume that the ROC curve looks like the mean on the graph provided
 [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc_crossval.html#example-model-selection-plot-roc-crossval-py).

Assuming you train a SVM on the entire dataset at default settings, where will it lie on the ROC curve

**EDIT:** Clarification

Assume I train a SVM at default values (sklearn), how would I determine where on the ROC curve it was. Alternatively, which setting on the SVC class allows me to set ROC position?

Comment: this is not a stackoverflow questiion, it is a [crossvalidated question](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: ROC is a metric to describe how well your classifier is classifying.  What do you mean by "trying to find the exact position"?  ROC will be different for different datasets.

Comment: the threshold of the classifier output / the position on the ROC curve you would select depends e.g. on the [false positive rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positive_rate) you are willing to accept.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding the concept of an ROC. A model doesn't "lie on the ROC", a model **has** an ROC curve. This can be used for evaluating your model, or for deciding how you're going to use your model.

### Evaluating your model's performance

To calculate the ROC of your model, use the `roc_curve` function, with inputs as the predicted probabilities from your model, and the actual results:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
roc = roc_curve(model.predict_proba(X), y)
```

If you want a single measure of your model's performance, you can use the **area under the ROC**; this can be useful if you're trying to tune hyperparamaters of your model, optimise your feature selection, etc. A typical way to calculate this (with k-fold cross validation) in `sklearn` would be:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
cross_val_score(model, X, y, scoring = 'roc_auc')
```

### Using your model to predict.

If you just call model.predict(X), the model will predict based on a probability threshold of 0.5. This is probably not what you want: as @AndreHolzner pointed out in the comment to your question, you'll want to use your ROC curve to decide the false positive rate that you're willing to accept. After this you just check whether your predicted probabilities are above this threshold or not:

```
thresh = 0.8
predictions = model.predict_proba(X) > thresh
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped quite a bit.